# gnu-parallel doesn't work without trailing commas in CSV

Tags: csv, gnu-parallel

I have the following parallel command that I run

```sh
parallel --header : --colsep , \
  python -m imitation.scripts.train \
  with \
  "$@" \
  gail \
  {env_config} \
  log_root="${OUTPUT_DIR}" \
  init_trainer_kwargs.rollout_glob=expert_models/rollouts/{rollout_glob} \
  init_trainer_kwargs.n_expert_demos={n_demonstrations} \
  :::: experiments/gail_benchmark_config.csv
```

which pulls out `{rollout_glob}`, `{n_demonstrations}`, and `{env_config}` from the following csv file:

```sh
$ cat -vet experiments/gail_benchmark_config.csv | head
env_config,rollout_glob,n_gen_steps_per_epoch,n_epochs,n_demonstrations^M$
cartpole,CartPole-v1.pkl,5000,300,1^M$
cartpole,CartPole-v1.pkl,5000,300,4^M$
cartpole,CartPole-v1.pkl,5000,300,7^M$
cartpole,CartPole-v1.pkl,5000,300,10^M$
mountain_car,MountainCar-v0.pkl,5000,300,1^M$
mountain_car,MountainCar-v0.pkl,5000,300,4^M$
mountain_car,MountainCar-v0.pkl,5000,300,7^M$
mountain_car,MountainCar-v0.pkl,5000,300,10^M$
acrobot,Acrobot-v1.pkl,5000,300,1^M$
```

It seems that `parallel` can't read `n_demonstrations` properly, and so it leaves `{n_demonstrations}` unfilled. I need to append a comma to the end of each CSV line to get my `parallel` script to work.

Example incorrectly generated command:

```sh
python -m imitation.scripts.train with gail cartpole [...] init_trainer_kwargs.n_expert_demos={n_demonstrations} seed=0
```

In other questions people seem to be [reading CSVs fine without using these trailing commas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38790690/1091722).

Anyone know what I can do differently so that I don't have to add trailing commas to my CSV? (This is annoying because it is equivalent to an empty column, and Google Sheets ignores empty columns when I'm trying to export [my CSV](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MZYTr23ddwhO2PrNI2EalKleoULXlsH5y9oqawt22pY/edit#gid=1428397235).)

Comment: Try `cat -vet YourFile.csv` to see any invisible characters at line ends.

Comment: Thanks, it turns out I had some trailing characters in my CSV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot produce your error. I have tested every version of GNU Parallel since 20120722, and all work fine if you remove the last `,`.

So something else is going on.

It can be in your environment. Can you find a different machine (e.g. a VM from http://www.osboxes.org/virtualbox-images/) and run it there?

It can be in the input file. Maybe there is characters that are invisible? Can you upload the actual file (preferably zipped/gzipped so we know nothing in it has changed)?

Comment: Thank you for throughly testing! As you guessed I had some invisible trailing characters in my CSV. In particular, in the first line of my CSV I had `n_demonstrations^M`, which doesn't match the `{n_demonstrations}` lookup in my parallel command.

Comment: Also, parallel is awesome. Kudos to you and the team :)

Comment: @protagonist Are you coming for the 10 years anniversary party? Or perhaps hosting your own? https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/10-years-anniversary.html

Comment: Thanks for bringing this celebration to my attention! I'll consider if there's a party in the SF bay area. (I'd expect to see lots of interesting, bearded Unix wizards there.)